# loop over songs accessing exifdata sequentially

Tags: bash, exif, exiftool

The Below code works is to sort my loose tracks from the +++ folder to the corresponding Artist/Loosies folder according to their exifdata. It will either copy or create a folder then copy.

Currently it works if i have only one song in the +++ directory, but as soon as i add two, the script stops at the first exiftool command.

*I'd like to make this work using bash, I realize  there may be a simpler/faster way to accomplish this with only exiftool, but i set out doing this to teach myself bash scripting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
loosies='Loosies'
for song in ~/Music/+++;
do
    artist=`exiftool -r -q -Artist $song` ;
    album=`exiftool -r -q -Album $song` ;
    title=`exiftool -r -q -title $song` ;
    title=${title#*: } ;
    album=${album#*: } ;
    artist=${artist#*: } ;
    if [[ -d  ~/Music/Artists/${artist} ]] ;
    then
        if [[ -d  ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${album} ]] ; then
            echo ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${album} ;
            cp -r $song/. ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${album} ;
        else
            mkdir ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${loosies} ;
            cp -r $song/. ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${loosies} ;
            if [[ -f ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${loosies}/${title} ]] ; then
                exiftool "${song}" -Artist -Album > ~/'success.txt';
            else
                exiftool "${song}" -Artist -Album > ~/'fail.txt';
            fi
        fi
    else
        mkdir ~/Music/Artists/$artist ;
        mkdir ~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${loosies} ;
        cp -r~/Music/Artists/${artist}/${loosies} ;
        if [[ -f ~/Music/Artists/$artist/$album/$title ]] ; then
            exiftool "${song}" -Artist -Album > ~/'success.txt';
        else
            exiftool "${song}" -Artist -Album > ~/'fail.txt';
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: You're sending a directory to exiftool, not a file. You need a glob: `..Music/+++/*`. Remove `-r` - it's recurse, not helpful for processing one file at a time. exiftool doesn't support writing to mp3s (only reading), so you'll need to do it like this anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answering @dan , all that makes sense. Removed the recursive -r 's and have been tinkering with the glob, can't seem to get it working. Am i supposed to add it in my for loop or in the exif command itself? With `~/Music/+++/*` in the for loop then it will print correctly, but keep getting errors when i add .. in front, or try to use exiftool on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it all figured out with the help of @dan 
Now works to search for an artists "Loosies" folder and create one if it isn't present.
Then copy the file there.
Lastly does a check if the file is in fact there and prints to a fail/success text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for song in ~/Music/+++/*;
do
    artist=`exiftool -Artist "${song}"`;
    title=`exiftool -title "${song}"`;
    title=${title#*: } ;
    artist=${artist#*: } ;
    if [[ -d  ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}" ]] ;
    then
        if [[ -d  ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}"/Loosies ]] ; then
            cp  "${song}" ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}"/Loosies ;
        else
            mkdir -p ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}"/Loosies ;
            cp  "${song}" ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}"/Loosies ;
        fi
    else
        mkdir -p ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}"/Loosies ;
        cp "${song}" ~/Music/Artists/"${artist}"/Loosies ;
    fi
    song_=${song##*/}
    if [[ -f ~/Music/Artists/$artist/Loosies/$song_ ]] ; then
        exiftool "${song}" -Album -Artist -title >> ~/'success.txt';
        echo '---' >> ~/'success.txt';
    else
        exiftool "${song}" -Album -Artist -title >> ~/'fail.txt';
        echo '---' >> ~/'fail.txt';
    fi
done
```